# knockoutjs updated the table after edit

Tags: knockout.js

how to update the table after upate is done. heres my sample code. If you click update the table is not updating.

```
 self.updateCategory = function(category){
        var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to update this category " + self.ID() + "?");
        if(r==true){
            //code here?
        }
    };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/comfreakph/2TrjF/3/

Comment: Your jsfiddle seems to work correctly, what are you asking?

Comment: if you click update button. the table is not updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things you need to do. First off, use the [knockout mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html), and then set up the Categories property using that:

```
self.Categories = ko.mapping.fromJS(category);
```

Your code is making the array observable, but not each item in it. By using the mapping plugin, you make each category and all its properties observable.

Then you need to update your update function to get the original category out and *update* the values on it:

```
self.updateCategory = function (category) {
    var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to update this category " + self.ID() + "?");
    if (r == true) {
    var original = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.Categories(), function (item)
    {
        return category.ID() == item.ID();
    });
        console.log(original.CreatedAt());
        original.Name(self.Name());
        original.Remarks(self.Remarks());

        self.Name("");
        self.Remarks("");
        self.isSelected(true);
        }
    };
```

You should find that the row in the table is automatically updated when you change the values.

[jsFiddle available](http://jsfiddle.net/2TrjF/10/).

Comment: @comfreakph No problem, glad to help! JHowever, nothing says thank you like an up-vote though. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's not updating because you have no code :-)

```
self.updateCategory = function(category) {
   var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to update this category " + self.ID() + "?");
   if(r == true) {
      // Code here?
   }
};
```

If you are asking how, then in the "// Code here" section you need to then find the category in the array from the ID you saved, an then set its properties from the self.Name and self.Remarks properties.

Answer (score 0):

This is a crude solution but it seems to work> I try to find the orginal element based on the ID and then replace with the new element created from the data. 
I am sure there could more efficient ways to find the original but the idea is you can do a replace on the observable array.

```
self.updateCategory = function (category) {
    var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to update this category " + self.ID() + "?");
    if (r == true) {
        var index = -1; 
        $.each(self.Categories(), function (i, item) {
            if (this.ID === category.ID()) {
                index = i;
            }
        });
        var original = self.Categories()[index];
        console.log(original.CreatedAt);
        category.Name = self.Name();
        category.Remarks = self.Remarks();
        category.CreatedAt = original.CreatedAt;

        self.Categories.replace(original, category);
        self.Name("");
        self.Remarks("");
        self.isSelected(true);
        }
    };
```

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2TrjF/5/

Comment: As you say, it's a bit crude! If you make the underlying Categories property completely observable, it's cleaner and easier. See my answer for what I mean.